# Where is the closed stream here, and how can I open it?

Tags: c#, image, stream, itext, virtual-directory

I'm trying to add an image to a PDF file using iTextSharp. I got the idea for my code from [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/87/itextsharp-working-with-images), and it is:

```
string imagepath = Server.MapPath("Pictures");
iTextSharp.text.Image png = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagepath + "/OfficeUseOnlyImg.png");
doc.Add(png);
```

The err occurs on the middle line, where GetInstance() is called.

So what's the "closed stream" jazz? If I'm supposed to open a stream for this operation, how/where/what?

Here is my code (which was working fine until I tried to add the image with the code above) for some context:

```
private void GeneratePDF(List<ListColumns> listOfListItems)
{
    //Create a stream that we can write to, in this case a MemoryStream
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 10, 10)) 
        {
            //Create a writer that's bound to our PDF abstraction and our 
stream
            using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
            {

                //Open the document for writing
                doc.Open();

                Paragraph docTitle = new Paragraph("UCSC - Direct Payment 
Form", timesBold16UCSCBlue);
                doc.Add(docTitle);

                Paragraph subTitle = new Paragraph("(Not to be used for 
reimbursement of services)", timesRoman9Font);
                subTitle.IndentationLeft = 20;
                doc.Add(subTitle);

                // Build up chunkified combination of "important notice"
                Chunk boldpart = new Chunk("Important: ", 
helvetica9BoldRed);
                Chunk ini = new Chunk("Form must be filled out in ", 
helvetica9Red);

                Anchor anchor = new Anchor("Adobe Reader", LinkFont);
                anchor.Reference = "http://www.adobe.com";

                . . . // other similar code delided for brevity and 
conservation of electrons

                string imagepath = Server.MapPath("Images");
                iTextSharp.text.Image png = 
iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagepath + "/OfficeUseOnlyImg.png");
                doc.Add(png);
```

So why does this rap my hand with a "Cannot access a closed Stream" err? I put the image file in the Libraries\Pictures folder (there is no "Images" folder, so I tried "Server.MapPath("Pictures")" but that doesn't work any better.

The value of imagepath after having Server.MapPath("Images") assigned to it is: "*C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\financial.ucsc.edu80\Pages\Images*"

I don't know if that is right, or if it's the problem, or if I need to place the image there, how to get to it to do so...

IN IIS Manager, I do see a "*SharePoint - financial.ucsc.edu80*" folder, but no "Pages" subfolder below that (let alone "Pages\Images").

### UPDATE

Even when I change imagepath (temporarily, for testing/POC purposes) to:

```
C:\Users\clayshan\Pictures\
```

...it still fails the File.Exists test.

So stepping through this code:

```
string imagepath = @"C:\Users\clayshan\Pictures\";
if (System.IO.File.Exists(imagepath + "OfficeUseOnlyImg.png"))
{
    iTextSharp.text.Image png = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagepath + "OfficeUseOnlyImg.png");
    doc.Add(png);
}

// Table for headings
PdfPTable tblHeadings = new PdfPTable(3);
. . .
```

..the "if" block is not entered, even though the imsage *is* there:

[image]

?!?

Is it the OS and its APIs that are playing tricks on me, or me eyes?

### UPDATE 2

Here's what the Command Prompt shows me:

[image]

...so, I still don't know just what path I should supply.

### UPDATE 3

As Lasse intimated, it was apparently a file access problem; by copying the file to C:\Users\Default, the following code works fine:

```
string imagepath = @"C:\Users\Default\";
if (System.IO.File.Exists(imagepath + "OfficeUseOnlyImg.png"))
{
    iTextSharp.text.Image png = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagepath + "OfficeUseOnlyImg.png");
    doc.Add(png);
}
```

Comment: Most likely the "closed stream" error is not your original error but occurs during disposal of the writer or document. To identify the actual error, please envelop the failing code with `try-catch` and inspect the exception you catch there.

Comment: It's happening on the call to GetInstance(), though...I'll try the catch block idea, at any rate.

Comment: Before adding the image try checking if `System.IO.File.Exists(imagepath + "/OfficeUseOnlyImg.png")` is true or false

Comment: It fails that test; imagepath is "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\financial.ucsc.edu80\Pages\Images" and it's not surprising that the image is not there, since I put it in the "Libraries\Pictures" folder on the server machine. So: how can I place the image there, so as to test this? As I note in my question, I see no such path extravaganza...

Comment: Setting imagepath to "imagepath = @"C:\Libraries\Pictures";" also fails that test, even though there *is* a copy of that file therein...

Comment: And the user folder on disk does not have a domain suffix?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Interesting thought - In Computer > Properties, I see "Domain: SP.LOCAL"; would replacing "C:\" with that be the right idea?

Comment: Just do a `dir` in the users folder, should see the real underlying folder then.

Comment: I'll add to Update 2 a scream shot of what I see in the "DOS box"

Comment: Hm, does File.Exists return false if the user you're running under doesn't have access rights to the file, perhaps?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: When it runs, I am the recognized user, so I don't know why access permissions would be a problem. The "clayshan" folder does have a padlock glyph barnacled onto it, so I'll try moving it to the unbarnacled "Default" subfolder of Users and see if that is seen.

Comment: I'll be darned - that works. It's a file access problem, then... Make an answer of your supposition, and I will give it its due fanfare (a mash of the old mouseroo).